# Open CV haarcascade file not found? I get this error: "<ipython-input-8-ad447f1b866f> in <module>()"

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Here is my code:]

[image: And I get these errors:]

Is it because I am using different versions of Python, or because my code is in another version of Python than it should be? I should be using Python3.

I tried different paths to the files, but haven't manage to find the right one yet.

Comment: Could you add your full stack trace to better help you

Comment: Also, Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `haarcascade` files in your `iPython` working directory and then run the program.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that the source image (img) has not been loaded. You can verify this by trying cv2.imshow(img)

With python, you have to use the absolute path to the image unless it is in the working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Totoro!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in line `ret, img = cap.read()`. Since you are reading frames from some external camera, You must verify if the device is ready to capture the frames and also if the frame returned are not empty. Generally `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` is called with param `0` which means the default camera device. But you have explicitly defined it as `1` which means you have 2 cameras connected with the device, and you want to access the external camera attached. If this is not the case, then you need to go through the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Other preventive measures can be sanity checks such as `if cap.isOpened()`, `img is not None`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had it defined as on, and this solved the problem.